# IIS is not refreshing files after I downloaded it once?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-10

We have an asp.net website, with a folder called *templates* with `Summaries.xlsx` and `Totals.txt`. The website has a link for the user to view these files.

After downloading `Summaries.xlsx` to my PC (ie. a copy was downloaded to my local Downloads folder), I decided to edit the original file where the website is set up. Even after editing and saving in the `IIS` folder, I'm still downloading the old version without the changes.

On the other hand, as soon as I edit the text file (which is displayed in the browser and is not "downloaded" to my local *Downloads* folder), I see the update.

The same thing happens if I erase both files from the server: I can still download the Excel file (that doesn't exist) but the txt file will display a 404 error.

I know it's a cache issue, But I can't ask all the users to clear their browser cache.

I tried the solution in this [forums.iis.net](https://forums.iis.net/t/1159847.aspx?File%20does%20not%20update) link, but it didn't help.

I've also tried recycling the App Pool, and nothing.

Finally, I installed `Application Request Routing Cache` but I don't see `Delete All Cached Objects` in the Actions pane.

Comment: we appended a random query string to the download URL. so that it considers as a fresh request everytime u click the link.   `var url = "http://whatever.com/Templates/Summaries.xlsx?dt=" + (new Date()).getTime();`

Comment: Thanks. Can this be included in the `navigateurl` property of `asp:HyperLink`?

Comment: "I can still download the Excel file (that doesn't exist)". That sounds wrong. I don't know how, but I would look into that, apart from chaching. Like delete the files on the server *and* your downloads folder (or wherever locally) and see what happens. See if you're really getting a file from the browser, or somehow from your local dir.

Comment: I can literally download the excel file even when it doesn’t exist in the server, but only if I had previously downloaded it.

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf  Is the hyperlink inside a Content page? `<asp:Content></asp:Content>`

Comment: Yes, its inside a Content page.

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf I have posted the answer. Take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `asp:HyperLink` is in the Content Page. you can create a javascript function and call it inside the `NavigateUrl` attribute

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DownloadFile(url) {
            document.location.href = url + "?dt=" + (new Date()).getTime();
        }
    </script>


    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:DownloadFile('/Templates/Summaries.xlsx')"> Summaries </asp:HyperLink>

</asp:Content>
```